# Issue with Python - loosing a life in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I've been having a bit of trouble with something in `pygame`. I'm trying to make it so that when a `plum` hits the ground (called `SCREENRECT` in the code), `LIVES` will subtract by 1.

The collision detection works for `SCORE`, but I just cannot figure out how to do `LIVES`. Any suggestions are welcome, and thank you. Code:

```
import random, os.path
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

if not pygame.image.get_extended():
     raise SystemExit("Sorry, extended image module required")

MAX_PLUMS = 30          #most dropping plums at once
PLUM_ODDS = 250         #chance a new plum will drop
PLUM_RESPAWN = 10       #frames between new plums
SCREENRECT = Rect(0, 0, 640, 480)   #screen size
SCORE = 0
LIVES = 3

main_dir = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]

def load_image(file):
    "loads an image, prepares it for play"
    file = os.path.join(main_dir, 'data', file)
    try:
        surface = pygame.image.load(file)
    except pygame.error:
        raise SystemExit('Could not load image "%s" %s'%(file, pygame.get_error()))
    return surface.convert()

def load_images(*files):
    imgs = []
    for file in files:
        imgs.append(load_image(file))
    return imgs

class dummysound:
    def play(self): pass

def load_sound(file):
    if not pygame.mixer: return dummysound()
    file = os.path.join(main_dir, 'data', file)
    try:
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(file)
        return sound
    except pygame.error:
        print ('Warning, unable to load, %s' % file)
    return dummysound()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    speed = 15
    bounce = 24
    images = []
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.containers)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=SCREENRECT.midbottom)
        self.origtop = self.rect.top
        self.facing = -1

    def move(self, direction):
        if direction: self.facing = direction
        self.rect.move_ip(direction*self.speed, 0)
        self.rect = self.rect.clamp(SCREENRECT)
        if direction < 0:
        self.image = self.images[0]
        elif direction > 0:
            self.image = self.images[1]
        self.rect.top = self.origtop - (self.rect.left//self.bounce%2)



class dropper(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    speed = 9
    animcycle = 12
    images = []
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.containers)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.facing = random.choice((-1,1)) * dropper.speed
        self.frame = 0
        if self.facing < 0:
            self.rect.right = SCREENRECT.right

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(self.facing, 0)
        if not SCREENRECT.contains(self.rect):
            self.facing = -self.facing;
            self.rect = self.rect.clamp(SCREENRECT)



class Explosion(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    defaultlife = 12
    animcycle = 3
    images = []
    def __init__(self, actor):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.containers)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=actor.rect.center)
        self.life = self.defaultlife

    def update(self):
        self.life = self.life - 1
        self.image = self.images[self.life//self.animcycle%2]
        if self.life <= 0: self.kill()



class Plum(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    speed = 9
    images = []
    def __init__(self, dropper):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.containers)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=dropper.rect.move(0,5).midbottom)

def update(self):
    self.rect.move_ip(0, self.speed)
    if self.rect.bottom >= 470:
        Explosion(self)
        self.kill()



class Score(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
        self.font.set_italic(1)
        self.color = Color('white')
        self.lastscore = -1
        self.update()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(10, 450)

    def update(self):
        if SCORE != self.lastscore:
        self.lastscore = SCORE
        msg = "Score: %d" % SCORE
        self.image = self.font.render(msg, 0, self.color)



class Lives(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
            def __init__(self):
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
                self.font.set_italic(1)
                self.color = Color('white')
                self.lastlife = -1
                self.update()
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(565, 450)

            def update(self):
                if LIVES != self.lastlife:
                    self.lastlife = LIVES
                    msg = "Lives: %d" % LIVES
                    self.image = self.font.render(msg, 0, self.color)



def main(winstyle = 0):
    pygame.init()
    if pygame.mixer and not pygame.mixer.get_init():
        print ('Warning, no sound')
        pygame.mixer = None

    winstyle = 0 
    bestdepth = pygame.display.mode_ok(SCREENRECT.size, winstyle, 32)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREENRECT.size, winstyle, bestdepth)

    img = load_image('player1.gif')
    Player.images = [img, pygame.transform.flip(img, 1, 0)]
    img = load_image('explosion1.gif')
    Explosion.images = [img, pygame.transform.flip(img, 1, 1)]
    dropper.images = load_images('dropper.gif')
    Plum.images = [load_image('plum.gif')]

    icon = pygame.transform.scale(Plum.images[0], (32, 32))
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Plum Picker')
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

    bgdtile = load_image('background.gif')
    background = pygame.Surface(SCREENRECT.size)
    for x in range(0, SCREENRECT.width, bgdtile.get_width()):
        background.blit(bgdtile, (x, 0))
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    boom_sound = load_sound('boom.wav')
    shoot_sound = load_sound('car_door.wav')
    if pygame.mixer:
        music = os.path.join(main_dir, 'data', 'house_lo.wav')
        pygame.mixer.music.load(music)
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    droppers = pygame.sprite.Group()
    plums = pygame.sprite.Group()
    all = pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates()
    lastdropper = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()

    Player.containers = all
    dropper.containers = droppers, all, lastdropper
    Plum.containers ums, all
    Explosion.containers = all
    Score.containers = all
    Lives.containers = all

    global score
    plumrespawn = PLUM_RESPAWN
    kills = 0
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    global SCORE
    global LIVES
    player = Player()
    dropper()
    if pygame.font:
        all.add(Score())
        all.add(Lives())



    while player.alive():
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or \
                (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                    return
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        all.clear(screen, background)

        all.update()

        direction = keystate[K_RIGHT] - keystate[K_LEFT]
        player.move(direction)

        # Create new dropper
        if plumrespawn:
            plumrespawn = plumrespawn - 1
        elif not int(random.random() * PLUM_ODDS):
            dropper()
            plumrespawn = PLUM_RESPAWN

        # Drop plums
        if lastdropper and not int(random.random() * PLUM_ODDS):
           Plum(lastdropper.sprite)

        for plum in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, plums, 1):
            boom_sound.play()
            SCORE = SCORE + 1

#LIVES NEEDS TO BE HERE. I THINK IT NEEDS TO BE SOMETHING LIKE:
    #for plum in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(SCREENRECT, plums, 1):
        #boom_sound.play()
        #LIVES = LIVES - 1


        if LIVES == 0:
            player.kill()

        #draw the scene
        dirty = all.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update(dirty)

        clock.tick(40)

    if pygame.mixer:
        pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(1000)
    pygame.time.wait(1000)
    pygame.quit()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, avoiding the use of globals could help you structuring you code. I'm not saying globals are evil, but try to see them as a last resort.

Comment: Thank you for that, this is my first time posting to stackoverflow, so wasn't sure if I got everything correct in my post. I'll try out what you said and see if it works. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking the collisions between plums and Rect(0, 0, 640, 480) you will notice that the plums are constantly contained within the rectangle.

Try:

```
for plum in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(Rect(0,480,640,50), plums, 1):
        boom_sound.play()
        LIVES = LIVES - 1
```

I haven't used pygame's sprites stuff for a long time so this may not be the case but it's worth a shot :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I tried out some of the stuff here and it's throwing a different error but hopefully I'll be able to fix it. I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: The error is related to the "for plum in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(Rect(0,480,640,50), plums, 1):" part. It says "TypeError: 'Group' object is not callable"